# How to troubleshoot an Apache reverse proxy?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, reverse-proxy, asp.net

As a heads up: I've asked this question on the Webmaster StackExchange and ServerFault and both times it got closed. On ServerFault I was redirected here.

I've been going out of my mind trying to figure out why this won't work. This is my first time working with Apache and CentOS. This is for a hobby website to help me build my skills.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have an ASP.NET Core application setup on the server. The files are in `/var/www/myapp`. I have a service setup for it and it is running and working on port 5000. I can cURL to it and get the proper response:

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '<json>' http://127.0.0.1:5000/graphql`

Now, I want to be able to interact with this application via a reverse proxy on my domain. I started by following the Microsoft documentation about this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1

That was not working for me so I started doing a bunch of research and I'm just lost. No matter what I do I am getting 404 errors. Not Found. God I'm sick of that lol. Here is where I'm at right now. I have a configuration file name `myapp.conf` in `/etc/apache2/conf.d`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <domain>.com
    ServerAlias *.<domain>.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ErrorLog /etc/apache2/logs/myapp-error.log
    CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/myapp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I know that my configuration file is being seen:

```
apachectl -S | grep myapp

*:80                   <domain>.com (/etc/apache2/conf.d/myapp.conf:1)
```

I know that the proxy modules are enabled:

```
httpd -M | grep proxy

 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
```

When I try to load them manually anyway just to be safe, Apache tells me that they're already enabled and skips them. I know that my configuration is okay as well:

```
apachectl -t

Syntax OK
```

I'm using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) to test the reverse proxy out. Here's what an exchange looks like:

```
* Preparing request to http://<domain>.com/graphql
* Using libcurl/7.69.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.1.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.40.0
* Current time is 2020-06-27T01:22:57.448Z
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 1 cookie
* Too old connection (488 seconds), disconnect it
* Connection 46 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 46
*   Trying <ip_address>:80...
* Connected to <domain>.com (<ip_address>) port 80 (#47)

> POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
> Host: <domain>.com
> User-Agent: insomnia/2020.2.2
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 343

| <json>

* upload completely sent off: 343 out of 343 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 27 Jun 2020 01:22:57 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 315
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1


* Received 315 B chunk
* Connection #47 to host <domain>.com left intact
```

Based on everything I've read ... there's no reason I should be getting these 404s. By the way, I've tried dozens and dozens of different ways of configuring each directive in the configuration file. I will happily do it all again if you have suggestions.

One thing that I've been trying to find out but have been unsuccessful is whether there is a way to test a request against your Apache setup and just see how Apache routes the request. So that would be nice if anyone knows.

Comment: what happens if you change `ProxyPreserveHost On` to `ProxyPreserveHost Off`

Comment: Nothing changed, I'm still getting the 404s when I hit 127.0.0.1:80 on the inside, and <domain>.com from the outside.

Comment: can you test this command `curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '<json>'  -H "Host: <domain>.com" http://127.0.0.1:5000/graphql`

Comment: this is to be sure that you app will accept all queries , see that i add a second `-H`.

Comment: @EchoMike444 Thank you for the suggestion, I ran that with the suggested host header and it worked properly. I tried it with other dummy hosts and it worked as well (subdomains and stuff like google.com).

Comment: Thanks @EchoMike444 this command worked for me, which leads me to believe its the proxy issue... However I still have no idea what it could be :D

Answer (score 1):

So after much trial and error, I think the issue is that my virtual host definition was just being processed after the default one in httpd.conf. When I changed the virtual host definition to listen on the server's IP address rather than `*:80`, it worked.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
</VirtualHost>

to

<VirtualHost <my-server-ip-address>:80>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like to figure out why *:80 won't work but perhaps that is for another day.